# How to skew a ul li but not the <a> in ul li a?

Tags: css, css-transforms, skew

I have a `ul li a` menu and want to skew the `ul li` but not the `a`. The `ul li` skews, but the `a` won't skew to normal position.

```css
header ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #f5c207;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    transform: skew(-20deg);
}
header ul li a {
    transform: skew(20deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="top" class="container">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">About us</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Other</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: on mac and google chrome it looks fine to me...

Comment: Not for me (also Mac and Google Chrome). OP.. maybe use `:after` for the background.

Comment: @Blazemonger please don't change the code; that could be exactly what his problem is

Comment: He said it skews, but won't skew back. That wouldn't happen if the CSS wasn't being applied at all.

Comment: @MehdiYaghoubi You need to start with using `<header>` elements in your HTML, or use `div` in your selector, and see if that fixes your problem. Your HTML and CSS need to match, in other words.

Comment: @Blazemonger I know, but it's OP's responsibility to provide the code he has; it's not your responsibility to guess.

Comment: after removing .header I see the issue now

Comment: @TylerH Tell you what: you wait for an answer from OP, and in the meantime, I'll just be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't skew inline elements, try this:

```css
header ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #f5c207;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    transform: skew(-20deg);
}
header ul li a {
    display:inline-block;
    transform: skew(20deg);
}
```

```html
<header id="top" class="container">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">About us</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Other</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</header>
```

Comment: There is another way to doing this. We can use pseudo class rather changing to the element. We can use this code.

    header ul li {
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 10px 20px;
      margin-left: 10px;
      position: relative;
    }
    header ul li:before {
      background: #000;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      content: "";
      z-index: -1;
    }
    header ul li a {
      display:inline-block;
      color:#fff;
    }

Answer (score 4):

You need to add `display: block` (or `inline-block`) to the `a` inside the list items.

```css
header ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #f5c207;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  transform: skew(-20deg);
}

header ul li a {
  display: block;
  transform: skew(20deg);
}
```

```html
<header id="top" class="container">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">About us</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Other</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to skew an inline element. Transforms can only be applied to transformable elements, most commonly block-level elements.
From the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#transformable-element):

> A transformable element is an element in one of these categories:
>   an element whose layout is governed by the CSS box model which is either a block-level or atomic inline-level element, or whose display property computes to table-row, table-row-group, table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-cell, or table-caption
>   an element in the SVG namespace and not governed by the CSS box model which has the attributes transform, ‘patternTransform‘ or gradientTransform.

To fix this set `a` to `display: inline-block;` or simply `display: block;`